# white box instead of an ai. image in indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm trying to export an Indesign file into PDF. It says that that particular element that doesn't show when exporting in PDF has a missing link. The element is in .ai format. It shows fine in Preview but not when exported (just a white space). I don't have an original .ai file that element. 
I'm a beginner so not sure how I can fix it :)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a missing link inside your document. Go to your Links panel (Window -> Links) and make sure there are no red question marks next to your graphics.

[image: missing link]

If you do have an object with a red question mark, right click and select Relink All instances of (name of layer). This will open up Finder (mac) or Explorer (Windows) where you can select the file to update the path.

If you do not have the file on your computer and the file is not embedded into the InDesign document then you will need to recreate the Illustrator file.